# How to store Key/Value values in a config for Consul

Tags: consul

I am using the Consul Docker Image on dockerhub. I wanted to know if there is a way to store the Key/Value settings in a config that the docker images can load on boot. I understand that the Image has the /consul/config and /consul/data volumes that can be used. but I have not found a way to achieve this.

The following is how I run consul

```
version: '3.4'
service:
  consul:
    container_name: consul
    image: consul:latest
    ports:
        - "8500:8500"
        - "8300:8300"
    volumes:
      - ./consul:/consul/config
```

In my host consul dir I have a file called config.json which contains the following

```
{
    "node_name": "consul_server",
    "data_dir": "/data",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
    "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
    "ui": true,
    "server": true,
    "bootstrap_expect": 1
}
```

Comment: What is your command to run the consul container? From https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/ I read: "Running the Consul container with no arguments will give you a Consul server in development mode."
and "The container exposes VOLUME /consul/data, which is a path were Consul will place its persisted state. This isn't used in any way when running in development mode"

Comment: @AntonioM I have updated my question to show the information you asked for. I am hoping there is a way in the config.json to add the Key/Values. but i have not seen any reference in the docs

Comment: Can you also add the container volume info from the running container? Just to make sure that the /data path points the directory on the host. From what I see in the docker config, I suspect the path is only present in the container and doesn't link to a directory on the host.